# Image used part of RAID5 onto smaller drive

Tags: raid, disk-image

I have a 2TB RAID5 of which 700GB is used and a 1TB empty hard drive. I'd like to image the RAID onto the drive (so I can later rebuild it using a different set of drives).

Looks like `dd` images the entire array, which won't fit. Is there a way to only image the used part?

[dd on entire disk, but do not want empty portion](https://serverfault.com/questions/439128/dd-on-entire-disk-but-do-not-want-empty-portion%20lists) lists a few ways, but there are some concerns about scalability and writing back using the image, and whether the approach works for RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need an image?  `rsync` will let you copy the contents of the filesystem to a filesystem on the empty hard drive, or to a filesystem on a loopback device if you need the data to be packaged up into a single file.

Imaging is nice if you need to preserve data that sits outside the filesystem (eg. boot sectors or partition tables), but that's not a common situation if you're using RAID 5.  It's overkill if you just need to clone the file tree.